# Submit in Spring form using DWR library

Tags: ajax, spring, dwr, spring-form

In one of J2EE project, we are using DWR libary. Being familiar with simple ajax calls and little DWR, I am not able to figure out which service call is used on our backend on clicking the submit button in one of our spring forms.

KRIDeclaration.jsp file: 
Spring Form tag :

```
<form:form commandName="KRIDeclarationCommand" name="krideclaration" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
........
Submit button: <td height="20" colspan="4" align="right" class="dvtCellLabel">
            <div align="center"><span style="padding-top: 5px;"> <input
                class="btnstyle" type="button" name="btnSendForApproval"
                 value="Submit" onClick="declareIncident();" />
```

KRIDecleration.js

```
declareIncident()
{
  Basic front end Validation
Backend Validation using DWR generated js file with a callback
}
callbackmethod(Result)
{
if (success)
document.krideclaration.submit();
else 
//code for displaying errors.

}
```

dwr-context.xml:

```
dwr:annotation-scan base-package="com.abc.riskdashboard.common" scanDataTransferObject="true" scanRemoteProxy="true" />

 <!-- DWR will map util.js and engine.js files to the dwrController.
  You can then include this files as external Javascript references from your JSP -->

 <dwr:url-mapping />

 <!-- Defines the dwrController. During production, set the debug property to false -->

 <dwr:controller id="dwrController" debug="true" />

 <!-- This is required if you want to configure any beans not managed by
  Spring. Leaving it enabled doesn't do any negative effects.
  -->

   <dwr:configuration>
   <dwr:convert type="bean" class="com.abc.riskdashboard.common.dto.RiskAreaMasterDTO" />
   <dwr:convert type="bean" class="com.abc.riskdashboard.common.dto.RiskIndicatorDTO" />
   <dwr:convert type="bean" class="com.abc.riskdashboard.common.dto.RiskDeclarationDTO" />
   <dwr:convert type="bean" class="com.abc.riskdashboard.common.dto.UserMasterDTO" />
   <dwr:convert type="bean" class="com.abc.riskdashboard.common.dto.RoleMasterDTO" />
```

Need to find out what  document.krideclaration.submit() in KRIDecleration.js calls when success. There is not submit function or action attribute in spring form